# Ansible: How to udpate dictionary key value in a file

Tags: ansible

Alright, thought it was going to be wasy, but I ended up scratching my head.

I have this `tracker.txt` file, in a dictionary style formatting:

```yaml
/oracle/db/19.0.0:
  rollback:
    30621255: 
    29213893: 
    29867728: 
    29802382: 
    28318139: 
  apply:
    28318139: 
    29213893: 
    28788272: 
    31431771: 
    32044280:
```

I am trying to make the file contents look like this in the end:

```yaml
/oracle/db/19.0.0:
  rollback:
    30621255: Success
    29213893: Success
    29867728: Success
    29802382: Success
    28318139: Success
  apply:
    28318139: 
    29213893: 
    28788272: 
    31431771: 
    32044280:
```

Here is my `uf.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    oracle_home: /oracle/db/19.0.0
    rblist: [30621255, 29213893, 29867728, 29802382, 28318139]
  tasks:
    - name: update file
      include: upd.yml
      with_items:
        - "{{ rblist | default([]) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: plist_item
      when: plist_item | default([])
```

and this is the `upd.yml` included task file

```yaml
---
- debug: msg={{ plist_item }}
- name: update the status
  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp="{{ plist_item }}:" replace="{{ plist_item }}: Success" after='rollback' before='apply'
```

But I get errors when I run this.

```
[oracle@anstrlsrv lib]$ ansible-playbook uf.yml

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [update file] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/stage/ap/ansible/lib/upd.yml': line 4, column 94, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: update the status\n  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp=\"{{ plist_item }}:\" replace=\"{{ plist_item }}: Success\" after='rollback' before='apply'\n                                                                                             ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/stage/ap/ansible/lib/upd.yml': line 4, column 94, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: update the status\n  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp=\"{{ plist_item }}:\" replace=\"{{ plist_item }}: Success\" after='rollback' before='apply'\n                                                                                             ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/stage/ap/ansible/lib/upd.yml': line 4, column 94, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: update the status\n  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp=\"{{ plist_item }}:\" replace=\"{{ plist_item }}: Success\" after='rollback' before='apply'\n                                                                                             ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/stage/ap/ansible/lib/upd.yml': line 4, column 94, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: update the status\n  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp=\"{{ plist_item }}:\" replace=\"{{ plist_item }}: Success\" after='rollback' before='apply'\n                                                                                             ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/stage/ap/ansible/lib/upd.yml': line 4, column 94, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: update the status\n  local_action replace: path=tracker.txt regexp=\"{{ plist_item }}:\" replace=\"{{ plist_item }}: Success\" after='rollback' before='apply'\n                                                                                             ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=5    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. Another option I thought was something that is documented here, but haven't ventured into it as I dont completely understand it yet: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/changing-deeply-nested-dict-variable-ansible-playbook

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes` => Quotes are effectively missing in your debug statement around the jinja2 expression: `- debug: msg="{{ plist_item }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    oracle_home: /oracle/db/19.0.0
    rblist: [30621255, 29213893]
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: tracker.txt
        name: tracker
    - copy:
        dest: tracker.txt
        content: |
          {
          '{{ oracle_home }}':
          {{ tracker[oracle_home]|combine({'rollback': rollback}) }}
          }

      vars:
        rsuccess: "{{ dict(rblist|product(['success'])) }}"
        rollback: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]['rollback']|combine(rsuccess) }}"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: tracker.txt
        name: tracker
    - debug:
        var: tracker
```

gives

```yaml
  tracker:
    /oracle/db/19.0.0:
      apply:
        '28318139': null
        '28788272': null
        '29213893': null
        '31431771': null
        '32044280': null
      rollback:
        '28318139': null
        '29213893': success
        '29802382': null
        '29867728': null
        '30621255': success
```

The file is stored in JSON

```sh
shell> cat tracker.txt
```

> {"/oracle/db/19.0.0": {"rollback": {"30621255": "success", "29213893": "success", "29867728": null, "29802382": null, "28318139": null, "30621255": "success", "29213893": "success"}, "apply": {"28318139": null, "29213893": null, "28788272": null, "31431771": null, "32044280": null}}}

---

Q: **"*Retain the file track.txt the way ... since its readability is better.*"**

A: It is possible. There are 2 options on how to use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/). Create the complete dictionary *tracker* and use filter [*to_nice_yaml*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json)

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: tracker.txt
        content: |
          {{ tracker|to_nice_yaml }}
```

The next option is to format the *content* by [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#indent) and *to_nice_yaml*. Both options would make the code more complex and error-prone. I'd [keep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) JSON. There is a [plethora of options on how to display JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=display+json). For example

```json
shell> cat tracker.txt | jq .
{
  "/oracle/db/19.0.0": {
    "rollback": {
      "30621255": "success",
      "29213893": "success",
      "29867728": null,
      "29802382": null,
      "28318139": null
    },
    "apply": {
      "28318139": null,
      "29213893": null,
      "28788272": null,
      "31431771": null,
      "32044280": null
    }
  }
}
```

---

**"*Understand the code*"**

1. Read the file and put the variables into the dictionary *tracker*

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: tracker.txt
        name: tracker
    - debug:
        var: tracker
```

gives

```yaml
  tracker:
    /oracle/db/19.0.0:
      apply:
        28318139: null
        28788272: null
        29213893: null
        31431771: null
        32044280: null
      rollback:
        28318139: null
        29213893: null
        29802382: null
        29867728: null
        30621255: null
```

2. Create the dictionary of succeeded patches

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: rsuccess
      vars:
        rsuccess: "{{ dict(rblist|product(['success'])) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  rsuccess:
    29213893: success
    30621255: success
```

3. Combine the *rollback* dictionary with *rsuccess*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ rollback }}"
      vars:
        rsuccess: "{{ dict(rblist|product(['success'])) }}"
        rollback: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]['rollback']|combine(rsuccess) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  rollback:
    28318139: null
    29213893: success
    29802382: null
    29867728: null
    30621255: success
```

4. Combine updated *rollback* with *oracle_home*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]|combine({'rollback': rollback}) }}"
      vars:
        rsuccess: "{{ dict(rblist|product(['success'])) }}"
        rollback: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]['rollback']|combine(rsuccess) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    apply:
      28318139: null
      28788272: null
      29213893: null
      31431771: null
      32044280: null
    rollback:
      28318139: null
      29213893: success
      29802382: null
      29867728: null
      30621255: success
```

5. Create the text block

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {
          '{{ oracle_home }}':
          {{ tracker[oracle_home]|combine({'rollback': rollback}) }}
          }

      vars:
        rsuccess: "{{ dict(rblist|product(['success'])) }}"
        rollback: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]['rollback']|combine(rsuccess) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    /oracle/db/19.0.0:
      apply:
        28318139: null
        28788272: null
        29213893: null
        31431771: null
        32044280: null
      rollback:
        28318139: null
        29213893: success
        29802382: null
        29867728: null
        30621255: success
```

---

Q: **with_items: "{{ rblist }}" "tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item].item": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"**

A: The items of *rblist* are integers. For some reason, the indexes do not evaluate to strings by default. Probably because of possible expected arithmetic inside the indexes. But, the keys in JSON have been stored as strings. For example, the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ item|type_debug }}"
      loop: "{{ tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'].keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        oracle_home: /oracle/db/19.0.0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 30621255 str
  msg: 29213893 str
  msg: 29867728 str
  msg: 29802382 str
  msg: 28318139 str
```

It's necessary to cast the keys to [string](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#string). For example, the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item|string]
      loop: "{{ rblist }}"
      vars:
        oracle_home: /oracle/db/19.0.0
        rblist: [30621255, 29213893]
```

gives

```yaml
  tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item|string]: success
  tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item|string]: success
```

Comment: Thank you once again! Is there a way to retain the file track.txt the way it was like in the dictionary format since its readability is better. Its not a big deal. I am still trying to understand your code to implement.

Comment: You're welcome! IMHO, it's not worth the effort. I'd keep JSON.

Comment: Thank you, starting to play with this now. I have gotten @anemyte's in place for now. A beer on me when you are here in Houston :)

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I was trying to access the success or null value from any of the items as follows.
'    - debug:
        var: tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item].item
      with_items: "{{ rblist }}"'
   
But getting this:
'ok: [localhost] => (item=30621255) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": 30621255, 
    "tracker[oracle_home]['rollback'][item].item": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}'
What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Explicit cast to string is necessary. I've updated the answer. (I was too quick with my previous answer. Sorry.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Vladimir Botka. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with YAML parser. You can avoid this by putting the line into quotes:

```yaml
- name: update the status
  local_action: "replace path=tracker.txt regexp='{{ plist_item }}:' replace='{{ plist_item }}: Success' after='rollback' before='apply'"
```

But I recommend you to rewrite this as a block for readability:

```yaml
- name: update the status
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1  # this replaces local_action
  replace:
    path: tracker.txt
    regexp: "{{ plist_item }}:"
    replace: "{{ plist_item }}: Success"
    after: rollback
    before: apply
```

Note that this code does not work with both `before` and `after`. I was able to make it work with either of these but somehow when both are present Ansible makes no change as if no match. You can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks @anemyte. Its working as you said after I implemented your suggestions. Appreciate your help.